# Outer class in static context

Tags: java

If there is a class with inner anonymous class like this:

```
class D {
    void j() {
        System.out.println("D");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D() {
            @Override
            void j() {
                System.out.println("Anonymous!");
            }
        };
        d.j();
        // D.this.j();
        // super.j();

    }
}
```

**How do I call "outer" method j() which prints "D"?**
I know that if it was not in static (as main method is static) then I could use: 
**D.this.j();** 
And I know that the j() method in anonymous inner class is overriding the j() method in class D but I can't use **super.j();** neither - compiler says: 
Cannot use super in a static context). 
It looks like D.j() can't be called from that place in code but I just want to be sure. 
Any toughs about this?

Comment: calling super.j() from the overridden j() method works just fine. Show us what you're trying to do. It's unclear where you would like to call D.j().

Comment: @JBNizet OK, I added two commented lines.

Comment: Then the presence of the d variable and the existence of the anonymous inner class. You just want to create an instance of D, and to call it's j() method, just like Tan_Blaytan's answer shows.

Comment: Why down vote for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a non-static things in a static context.

`this`, `super` - non-static things, they don't exist in static context

You need to initialize object `D` and then invoke `j()` method through reference:

```
new D().j();
```

I think it'll help you to figure out:

```
class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // static context
        D a = new D() {
            // only non-static methods and fields
            @Override
            void j() {
                // non-static context - possible to use  'super' and 'this' keywords
            }
        };
    }

    void j() {
        // non-static context - possible to use  'super' and 'this' keywords
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - no need to explain - I said that I know that if it was not in static (as main method is static) then I could use: D.this.j();  - I put // D.this.j(); and  // super.j(); just to illustrate the spot where from I want to call method in D. What haven't came to my mind is that I could create another object dd without inner class or to use use: new D().j(); <-- that is solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just instantiate the *D* class inside the main method:

```
D dd = new D();
dd.j();
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution - I accepted the other one just because I prefer (in this context): new D().j();

Comment: You are very welcome, that's fine, you are free to accept any answer you think is better.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve the problem - both require modification of one of the classes.

## 1. Implementation / Fallback Method

You can introduce a 'fallback' method into your `D` class that can then be called normally.

```
void j() {
    fallback();
}

void fallback() {
    System.out.println("D");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    D d = new D() {
        @Override
        void j() {
            System.out.println("Anonymous!");
        }
    };
    d.j(); // prints 'Anonymous!'
    d.fallback(); // prints 'D'
}
```

## 2. Helper Method in the Anonymous Class

If you don't have edit access to the parent `D` class, for example because it comes from a library, you can introduce a method in your anonymous class that calls the `super` implementation.

```
void j() {
    fallback();
}

void fallback() {
    System.out.println("D");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    class AnonD extends D{
        @Override
        void j() {
            System.out.println("Anonymous!");
        }

        void superJ() {
            super.j();
        }
    }
    AnonD d = new AnonD();
    d.j(); // prints 'Anonymous!'
    d.superJ(); // prints 'D'
}
```

This has the minor drawback that you need to name your anonymous class. You don't have to make it a top-level class declaration though, because you can also declare it locally for the method it is used in.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer i was looking for but thanks for effort. Up voted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are created the method `j()` in a non-static context.

A viable solution is to make `j()` static by adding the 'static' keyword in front of j, as such:

```
static void j(){...}
```

This now allows you to access `j()` in a 'static context', as your error specified.